# In Angular 9, when setting a form to local storage, how do I specify certain parameters DON'T get saved?

Tags: angular, local-storage

Here is my code:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
    persistForm = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ActionLoginFormUpdate>(LoginFormActionTypes.UPDATE),
    distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y)),
    tap(action => {
        this.localStorageService.setItem(LOGIN_FORM_KEY, { form: action.login.loginForm })
    })
);
```

login.loginForm contains Username and Password. I don't want it to save Password, only username. How do I make it so it only saves username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize spread operator to achieve that try below code :

```
const {password,...rest} = action.login.loginForm;
```

this will assign password property, and `rest` will be populated with the rest of the porperties. And then you can assign your form like this :

```
this.localStorageService.setItem(LOGIN_FORM_KEY, { form: rest})
```

Comment: Hello your solution works for me when I check the browser saved data. It only saved username, not password. However, the password field is still populated, I'm guessing due to it being saved in Session data? Is there a way to prevent this or is this alright?

Comment: @Soulzityr you can ignore that.

Comment: Hello, I would still like to remove it. Is there a way? @Eldar

Comment: @Soulzityr it will be gone when the current scope completed. The solution built up on the property name, so for this there is no way to get rid of it. But its not a problem.

Comment: "The solution built up on the property name, so for this there is no way to get rid of it". What does it mean, "The solution built up on the property name?" Thank you.

Comment: @Soulzityr in object destructure opreation assignments done with the property names if you want the properties you need exact property names at the left side of the assignment

Comment: What does that mean? I need the password field to never save. I'm sure there is a way to do it, other sites do not automatically throw your password in after you input it once.

Comment: @Soulzityr don't worry assigning it to a variable in a scope won't save it.

Comment: But it autopopulates the password field and I would like it to not do that. Sorry I meant autopopulate, not save.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219283/discussion-between-soulzityr-and-eldar).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there your question is not angular specific In order to remove certain properties from an object you can use the delete keyword in javascript.

An example for your case
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp

You have to manually delete each property from the object you dont want to be saved